# How to embed H2 database into jar file delivered to the client?

Tags: java, database, jar, h2

I use H2 database for a desktop application in embedded mode. When I compress the application into jar file the database file is omitted. So, when I run MyApplication.jar nothing works. What is the correct way to embed/include/connect h2.jar file with MyApplication.jar? Or maybe there is another way to deliver database and application in the bundle?

Comment: How are you creating this JARfile? Are you using a build tool such as Maven, or simply running `jar` from the command-line?

Comment: I use Eclipse. There is an option to export to jar file, so I use that option.

Comment: I recommend taking the time to learn Maven: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/public-book.html -- over the long term, that investment will repay itself many times over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One common scheme is to put `h2.jar` in a `lib` directory relative to your application and include a `Class-Path` entry in your JAR's manifest with an entry for it:

```
Class-Path: lib/h2.jar lib/…
```

Addendum: This small [project](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/manifesto) includes a link to the [JAR specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/index.html) and a handy utility for examining the manifest *in situ*.

Comment: @bancer: I've elaborated above.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Maven to build your project, just use [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)... great results and control, I've been using it a lot.

For embedding all your dependencies you would write something like:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Then with just a normal "mvn package" you'll have all your dependencies' jars included in your application jar.

With further configuration you can control what gets included and what not.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put the *database* itself in your jar file, then this explanation might help:
http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_in_zip

This is also discussed in [this thread in the H2 forum](http://groups.google.com/group/h2-database/browse_thread/thread/e4b227272c0f66f7/57a00d47bd8e5c59?lnk=gst&q=database+in+jar+file).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using maven to build you project take a look maven-assembly-plugin (jar-with-dependencies). This would produce single jar with all dependencies packed into it.